# Threading on Android Tablet causing freezes

Tags: multithreading, delphi, firemonkey

I'm working on a Firemonkey application in Delphi Tokyo and decided to add a loader screen that does some animation.  I have a form with a list animation that is run within one thread, and then my calls to the datasnap server runs within another thread.  I'm doing it like this because I couldn't get the animation to work if both calls wasn't within a thread.

Now running this on the windows version works fine.  Running it on both my Huawei phone and another samsung tablet works 70% of the time.  The other 30% of the time it freezes and I have to kill the app.  When the datasnap load is done the loader form is supposed to be freed and closed and the main panels opacity is set to 1 and I enable the panel again.  I'm not sure 100% if the app freezes and if the code is not run successfully thats supposed to enable the panel again.  I was able to debug it one time while not working which produced an out of memory error, but I'm unable to recreate the issue while debugging on the phone.

The idea was that when the logging button is pressed a loader screen shows some animation while the data is retrieved and then hides it again.  Am I doing something wrong in the below code?

```
  ShowLoader;

  fThread := TTask.Create
  (
    procedure ()
    begin
      try
        LoDataset := fmxDataModule.ServerMethods.GetLoginDetails(edtEmail.Text, edtPassword.Text);
      except on E:Exception do
        begin
          TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread,
            procedure()
            begin
              ShowMessage('The system could not log you in.  Error Details: '+slinebreak+slinebreak+E.Message+slinebreak+slinebreak+'Please try again.');
              HideLoader;
            end
          )
        end;
      end;

      TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread,
        procedure()
        begin
          fmxDataModule.LoggedInUser.LoadFromDataset(LoDataset);
          if fmxDataModule.LoggedInUser.CompanyID.Value > 0 then
          begin
            Toolbarheader.Visible := True;
            lblLoginInfo.Visible := false;
            lblWelcome.Text := 'Welcome ' + fmxDataModule.LoggedInUser.FirstName.Value + ', ' + fmxDataModule.LoggedInUser.LastName.Value;
            GoToProfilesTab.Execute;
            GenerateProfiles;
            pnlButtons.Visible := True;
            fLoggedIn := True;
            FormResize(nil);
          end else
          begin
            lblLoginInfo.Visible := True;
            lblLoginInfo.Text := 'User does not exist, or login details invalid';
          end;
        end
      );

      HideLoader;
    end
  );

  fThread.Start;
```

Here is the code for ShowLoader:

```
procedure TfrmLogin.CreateLoaderForm;
begin
  if Assigned(fLoader) then
    FreeAndNil(fLoader);
  fLoader := TfrmLoader.Create(Self);
  floader.Parent := Self;
  fLoader.Left := Self.Left + (Self.Width div 2) - (fLoader.Width div 2);
  fLoader.Top  := Self.Top + (Self.Height div 2) - (fLoader.Height div 2);
  fLoader.Show;
end;

procedure TfrmLogin.ShowLoader;
begin

  pnlMain.Enabled := false;
  pnlMain.Opacity := 0.4;

  TTask.Create (
    procedure ()
        begin

          TThread.Queue(TThread.CurrentThread,
            procedure()
            begin
              CreateLoaderForm
            end);

        end
    ).Start;

end;
```

Hiding the loader:

```
procedure TfrmLogin.HideLoader;
begin
  pnlMain.Enabled := True;
  pnlMain.Opacity := 1;
//  pnlMain.Repaint;
  fLoader.Visible := False;
end;
```

Am I missing something in the code above?

Another question is why does my form not open in the middle of the screen?  I've tried different things, setting the position in the form properties, and manually calculating it.  It always opens up top left corner on the device, but works on windows.

Comment: I think you'll find that `TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure begin end ).Start` is more suited to your purposes here. I stopped using TTask for simple threads on Android quite some time ago.

Comment: Thanx, I'll give it ago to see if it helps me.

Comment: Didn't seem to change anything

Comment: Note, your use of `edtEmail` and `edtPassword` must be synchronized. Better to save those `Text` values to local `string` variables and let the anonymous procedure capture them. Also, in `ShowLoader()` you can replace `TTask`+`TThread.Queue()` with `TThread.ForceQueue()`

Comment: @FrankPedro There is a lot going on in your code so that I could write a page of comments on this! Also, not all the code is shown. We can't help you debug your app. "Write simpler code" is what I always tell myself.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I actually also wondered about the mail and password fields not being syncronized.  I'm not an expert with threading, but that did caught my eye.  I'll give your comments ago and see if it changes anything.  Any other idea what could be causing this sporadic behaviour? I have no issues on the windows side...

Comment: @nolaspeaker, thank you.  This is by no means the finished product.  I'm just trying to get a few things working at first.

Comment: Of course. In Android dev, often the path to success results from being versatile. Write another version of your code that uses an AniIndicator rather than a separate form, for instance.

Comment: @nolaspeaker, wow, I wasn't even aware that there was a built in type of spinner like this.  The reason I have a separate form is because I'm animating my own version of a spinner with our company logo and I wanted to keep it separate.  I was looking up last week how to use an animated gif to create a spinner effect and I couldn't find anything so I resorted to using the List Animation.  That's what the separate form is for...

Comment: I do however see that if I use this indicator I don't need to run it also within a separate thread like my example above.  The call to datasnap is already within a thread and doesn't freeze up my spinner like my first attempt did.  I'm going to try this route to see if it's not better

Comment: @nolaspeaker, thank you for your suggestion.  If it wasn't for your suggestion I wouldn't have derived at the issue.

Answer (score 1):

After trying a different approach like @nolaspeaker suggested, and syncronising the username and passwords fields like @RemyLebeau suggested, I removed the form loader that was in a different thread, and the problem still persisted.  Doing that became obvious that there must be a problem in the below piece of code I posted initially, only a bit refactored:

```
TThread.CreateAnonymousThread
  (
    procedure
    var
      LsUsername,LsPassword:String;
    begin
      try
        TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread,
          procedure()
          begin
            LsUsername := edtEmail.Text;
            LsPassword := edtPassword.Text;
          end
        );

        LoDataset := fmxDataModule.ServerMethods.GetLoginDetails(LsUsername, LsPassword);
      except on E:Exception do
        begin
          TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread,
            procedure()
            begin
              ShowMessage('The system could not log you in.  Error Details: '+slinebreak+slinebreak+E.Message+slinebreak+slinebreak+'Please try again.');
              HideLoader;
            end
          )
        end;
      end;


      TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread,
        procedure()
        begin
          fmxDataModule.LoggedInUser.LoadFromDataset(LoDataset);
          if fmxDataModule.LoggedInUser.CompanyID.Value > 0 then
            GoToProfilesTab.Execute
          else
          begin
            lblLoginInfo.Visible := True;
            lblLoginInfo.Text := 'User does not exist, or login details invalid';
          end;
        end
      );

      HideLoader;
    end
  ).Start;
```

Trying a couple more times to debug the scenario I ended up in `TTabControl.SetActiveTabWithTransition`.

The issue occurs on this line

```
LocalAnimateIntWait(Layout2, 'Position.X', Round(P.X), Duration, TAnimationType.In,
              TInterpolationType.Linear);
```

in this block of code:

```
procedure TTabControl.SetActiveTabWithTransition(const ATab: TTabItem; ATransition: TTabTransition;
const ADirection: TTabTransitionDirection = TTabTransitionDirection.Normal);

  ...
begin
  case ATransition of
    TTabTransition.Slide:
      begin
        FTransitionRunning := True;
        ClipChildren := True;
        try
          ...

          if ADirection = TTabTransitionDirection.Normal then
          begin
            P...
          end
          else
          begin
            ...


            LocalAnimateIntWait(Layout2, 'Position.X', Round(P.X), Duration, TAnimationType.In,
              TInterpolationType.Linear);


          end;
        finally
          SetLength(FTransitionTabs, 0);
          ClipChildren := False;
          FTransitionRunning := False;
          Realign;
        end;
        // Force repaint
        Application.ProcessMessages;
      end
  else
    ActiveTab := ATab;
  end;
end;
```

So I remove the tab transitioning for that one click and it finally works as expected.  The moment I put the transitioning back to Slide, it freezes again on that line. I'll be sure to report this issue.